# How I can invoke a std::function handle in the GDB debugger command line

Tags: c++, gdb, std, std-function

I have something like this:

```
bool foo(..., std::function<SomeType*> aFuncArg) {
   ...
    stmt1;  // Hit GDB breakpoint here
   ...
}
```

Then when I hit the breakpoint above in gdb within Emacs, I want to do this:

```
(gdb) p aFuncArg(argObj)
```

But this does not work. I get this:

```
Invalid data type for function to be called.
```

I can step through the function (through some layers, but that is another topic), but to do this I have to restart the debugging session. It would be convenient to execute the function from the GDB command line.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `(gdb) p aFuncArg(argObj)`
you can call operator() explicitly:

`(gdb) p aFuncArg.operator()(argObj)`

That seems to avoid the above error.